# Firestore trigger not working when run in emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Firebase and tried following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrzvBulgBi0&t=486s).

code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp()
const db = admin.firestore()
exports.onUserCreate = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {
const values = snapshot.data()
await db.collection('logging').add({description: `Email was sent to user with username:${values.username}`}) })
```

This should create a new collection called 'logging' whenever a new collection is created. But the trigger doesn't work in emulator, it shows only the collection which we created.

Comment: A new collection is automatically created when you create a new document using the `set()` method. There is no separate method for [creating collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections). 

Try adding a document as described in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

Comment: yes, it worked after I refreshed it a few times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my comment was helpful, posting it as an answer for visibility.

A new collection is automatically created when you create a new document using the `set()` method.

There is no separate method for creating [collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections). Try adding a document as described in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document). For example,

```
await db.collection('logging').doc('journal').set(data);
```